# Remove query parameters that Google appends to search results

Tags: java, web-crawler

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I have written a function in Java which connects to google.com and collects the first 200 search results returned given a query. However, Google appends some "funky" parameters to the original url so the original:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2013

becomes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_2013&sa=U&ei=EPiIUuSGB5OV7AbB0YCQCA&ved=0CCMQFjAD&usg=AFQjCNEsQZZJUO1CU7cCwBaUDAXP9LSsjQ.

Now this would not be a problem since I could just cut the String at the point where I encounter "&sa..". However, Google appends different parameters for different data types. So a PDF link contains one set of parameters, images another, websites a third one etc..

Do you know of a way where I can programatically remove the parameters that google appends in order to get the original url?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is within google's terms of use?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. If that was possible it would be a security risk.